# Can my excess baggage be refused?

Tags: luggage, qatar-airways

I will be flying from Australia to the Czech Republic (stopover in Doha) with Qatar Airways. I am allotted 30 kgs of check-in baggage, but I will go over that. I will have:

- One luggage that is 26 kilograms (or thereabout, my scales are not so accurate).
- One backpack that is 6.5 kilograms.

I have 2 questions:

- Will Qatar Airways let me check in the 24-kg luggage? I have heard that they can refuse if the bag is over 20 kilograms.
- Do you recommend I purchase extra baggage now online or when I go to check in 3 hours before flying? Is it possible they will refuse my extra baggage when I go to checkin?

*I am relocating to another country so I am not able to reduce my luggage any less than what I have now.

Answer (score 8):

**They can refuse it actually.** I learned this just last year the hard way and had to use luggage courrier service or shipping company instead. Even worse, they accepted on the way *to* but refused when we were going *back* which left us no choice but to emergency ship which is very costly.

Normally, there is a fee for excess weight up to a certain amount. With Qatar, the fee is per additional kg, depending on the end-points of your journey, and up to a maximum of 32kg per bag. Since there is a fee, they are usually happy to charge you and transport your luggage, except that they may decide that the flight is too loaded and refuse to take it. It happened another time that an airline accepted my excess but sent it on the next flight, so it seems to be up to them.

The best you can do is purchase the excess luggage in advance and that will secure your baggage allowance. Last year, it is when I went to purchase ahead of time that I was not allowed. So if they let you pay for it, you should be pretty much good to go, even if they send it on a later flight. If you cannot purchase the excess in advance, call them as soon as possible and make arrangements if they tell you it will not be possible. They are companies that specialize in shipping luggage but are fairly pricey so also check with generic shipping services. They may have odd requirements. For example, DHL required it to be a box and said if I shipped a suitcase, it had to be boxed while the courrier service only took suitcases and Delta does not access boxes at all airports, so it is possible to go with a box and not be let back on the return journey with it.

Comment: Just curious: did they gave you an option to throw away some less valuable items of your luggage? Sometimes it would be cheaper than paying excess fee

Comment: That did happen but with Emirates. I just gave them the 'extra' items as gifts. They laughed and left them behind the check-in counter. You can also move some weight to your carry-on but I was at max there too. It was a long trip involving many airlines with different rules, so i had to improvise including mailing myself some stuff using the Czech Postal service which is quite difficult if you do not speak Czech.